# Subtaskflow is getting suspended instead of failed in IICS

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, iics

I am new to IICS, we have one task flow where there are three sub taskflows inside it and inside sub taskflows we have datatasks so now if the datatask fails the subtaskflow is going into suspended mode but not into failed mode. We have tried several changes in error handling and also tried throw option but no use.What changes needs to be made to make it to failed state instead of suspended state, kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Review the [following post](https://network.informatica.com/s/question/0D56S0000AD6j48SQB/advanced-taskflow-failure-notifications) (make sure to expand the answer to see images). Basically you need to make sure errors are properly handled be **EVERY** task in your taskflows.